# Extra padding or margin on custom font in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, font-face

I have a couple of fonts that I downloaded as a kit (ttf, eot, woff, etc).  However, in Chrome, they seem to have extra `padding` or `margin` that does not show up in Internet Explorer or Firefox.  it seems to be top and bottom.

I did all the obvious css tricks like:

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

But this seems to be an issue with the font themselves.

Here is one of the fonts:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bebas';
    src: url('bebas.eot');
    src: url('bebas.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('bebas.woff') format('woff'), url('bebas.svg#BebasRegular') format('svg'), url('bebas.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

does anyone know any coding tricks to fix or a better way to convert/download?

Comment: Have you tried the line-height property?

Comment: Why don't you use TypeKit or Google Web Fonts. They don't seem to have any issues like padding or margins. I must tell you that different browser engines render things differently so expect that anyway in your case as well.

Comment: Fonts usually have a bit of whitespace on the top and bottom so there is not really anything you can do about that.

Comment: I have used `line-height`; doesn't fix.  The fonts I need are not listed on Google Web Fonts or Typekit; and would it be normal for them to have whitespace in ONE browser but not the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**FOR LIVE DEMO**](http://liveweave.com/obSK7G)

Bebas Neue is available on direct link source. margin 0 and padding 0 functions seem to be working fine.

```
tested in Chrome - works
tested in IE7 - works


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src='http://cdn.renderedfont.com/js/renderedfont-0.8.min.js#free'></script>


  body
  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  h1
  {
    font-family: "Bebas Neue", Arial; 
    font-size: 40px; 
    color: #99f;
  }



<h1 class="renderedFont">Bebas Neue</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll check this out! Bebas Neue is technically different but near identical - I think.  Didn't even think to try that.