# Anchor padding issue in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, web, anchor, padding

Over the past few days I've noticed that the spacing is off on my nav (when it displays this way):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVuFp.jpg

The site has been around for months and never had this problem. I think it only recently started happening in Chrome. You'll notice that if you go to the website: http://gw2shinies.com - it will almost always display correctly. This makes it extremely difficult for me to debug. Have any of you encountered this bug?

Comment: Yes, I'm also dealing with this, which just started after the latest Chrome update. It happens occasionally on all anchor tags (not just nav), and it happens almost half the time on my local dev site. Here is my site, where it rarely occurs on the latest version of Chrome: http://forrager.com
I don't see too many similarities between our sites. I am running Wordpress, Bootstrap, and many plugins. It's hard to nail down the issue, but it seems like it's a Chrome issue.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to certain types of custom fonts. On your site, you're using Bebas Neue, and on mine, I'm using Qlassik. Chrome renders both of these fonts with extra padding, on occasion (it's been happening a lot for me recently). The problem occurs on more than just anchor tags, and some pages of my site seem to be more vulnerable than others.

I downloaded Bebas Neue from both [here](http://fontfabric.com/bebas-neue/) and [here](http://www.dafont.com/bebas-neue.font), and then ran those through an [online converter](http://onlinefontconverter.com/), and neither of those worked.
I then downloaded Bebas from [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/bebas), converted it, and that did work.

I tried a ton of variations and tests. I try converting both the OTF and TTF files; I tested the unconverted TTF; I downloaded and converted other fonts from those sites and converted them; I simplified the @font-face declaration in my CSS; I tried a Google Font; I tried removing fallback fonts. The result of all of those tests suggest that there is simply something wrong with the font itself.

This is a terrible answer, but one guaranteed way to "fix" the problem is to change to a different font. In your case, you could try Bebas instead of Bebas Neue. In my case, I would have to abandon the font entirely.

Since this issue was first raised, Chrome has been updated and the issue persists. Part of me hopes that the issue will vanish in a future update, but that might not happen. It does appear that there is something in the core font file that isn't following some best practice. Bebas has had padding issues [in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219986/extra-padding-or-margin-on-custom-font-in-chrome). And honestly, Chrome has always struggled to render Qlassik cleanly (I have made CSS adjustments to compensate). I don't have the software or knowledge to update the font itself to eliminate the issue.

Comment: Thank you for that answer, your research has helped me out and I will consider making a new webfont.